# How do I apply shader to SVG Filter?

Tags: html, css, svg, webgl, svg-filters

I tried some WebGL technology before such as three js and pixi js. When I learned WebGL technology, I found **shader** which made me really fascinated. But WebGL can only be rendered on the canvas not the the HTML DOM. Then I kind of wonder if I could render that to the actual HTML DOM. I know that CSS Custom Filter can do such thing, but for the time being, Its not available yet on the modern browser. So I searched for another alternative, and then I found SVG Filter that I think could do almost close to what CSS Custom Filter does. But I've never used SVG filter before, **so first of all, how to use SVG Filter and I wonder if I could apply some shader to it ?**

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#filters to use shaders you'd need to create your SVG as an image, copy that image to a canvas and then do shading on the canvas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @RobertLongson, I know that would work, but  that's not what I'm looking for to do. So my question is Can we use SVG Filter on the div element on the HTML, instead of  the canvas ?

Comment: In some browsers you can, yes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

Comment: But can we apply shader to it ? that would be very nice

Comment: Only via the mechanism I already outlined in my first comment.